# Display Array Items in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble printing out the values stored in the array. It seems to be printing out the memory address instead. Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[4];
    int sum[4];
    
    printf ("Record the scores of the teams according to A:B, A:C, A:D, B:C, B:D and C:D.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; i + j < 4; j++) {
            scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
            scanf ("%d", &a[i + j]);
            sum[i] = sum[i] + a[i];
            sum[i + j] = sum[i + j] + a[i + j];
            printf ("%d\n", sum[i + j]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf ("%d\n", sum[i]);
        
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
Record the scores of the teams according to A:B, A:C, A:D, B:C, B:D and C:D.
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
3
3
3
3
```

Instead, it shows:

```
Record the scores of the teams according to A:B, A:C, A:D, B:C, B:D and C:D.
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
3
3
\-1646415677
21995
```

How should I solve this?

I want to know how to display what I have entered

Comment: You have a for loop that is less than 3 and another below that is less than 4, but both arrays have a size of 4

Comment: &a[i+j] will be out of bounds getting undefined behavior i.e. i + j > 3 will cause an error

Comment: @AndersK Loop condition should prevent that.

Comment: You need tell what this program is supposed to do. You're mixing actual inputs with output data. You're calculating total goals scored by each team in all matches. Also, make a provision for user input strings like `A:3::4:B` where team `A` scored `3`, while `B` scored `4`. That way both user & program have more control over their niche.

Answer (score 1):

Yoi have uninitialized variables. Fix:

```
int a[4] = { 0 };
int sum[4] = { 0 };
```

Single zero is enough, because C will have the rest initialized to 0 when you initialize just 1 element of a struct or an array.